# I have to convert a string in bytes for Modbus calc

Tags: string, hex, swift4, modbus, crc16

I have the following function in Swift 4:

```
import Foundation  
  
func crc16(of data: Data) -> String {  
    var crc = 0xffff as UInt16  
    for byte in data {  
        crc = crc ^ UInt16(byte)  
        for _ in 0..<8 {  
            if crc & 0x0001 == 0x0001 {  
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001  
            } else {  
                crc = crc >> 1  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    let msb = crc >> 8  
    let lsb = crc & 0x00ff  
    return String(format: "%02x%02x", lsb, msb)  
}
```

And I can calculate the CRC with that code:

```
print(crc16(of: Data(bytes: [0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0C]))) // -> ce9f
```

Now I ask, how can I modify that function for use that code:

```
print(crc16("11010003000C")) // -> ce9f
```

Instead of:

```
print(crc16(of: Data(bytes: [0x11,0x01,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x0C]))) // -> ce9f
```

Because I would like to create a simple application which permits me to insert the string "11010003000C" in an EditText, and in another editText show the result of the function "ce9f".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can write another version of `crc16` that takes a String for input. It then splits this string into substrings of 2 characters each and append them as bytes to the data structure:

```
func crc16(_ str: String) -> String {
    var data = Data()
    var startIndex = str.startIndex

    while startIndex < str.endIndex {
        let endIndex = str.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
        let substr = str[startIndex..<endIndex]
        data.append(UInt8(substr, radix: 16)!)
        startIndex = endIndex
    }
    return crc16(of: data)
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the reply! But with that code I receive an error: "error: terminated(1): /usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /swift-execution/.build/debug.yaml main
ERROR at line 16, col 17: extraneous argument label 'of:' in call
    return crc16(of: data)"

Comment: I had tried to modify the code (I have removed "of:" in the line of return, but without success.....